# ERROR: gcloud crashed (UploadError): Error uploading files: HttpError

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I tried to deploy an App Engine app but failed due to this error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (UploadError): Error uploading files: HttpError <redacted>
```

I already enabled:

- App Engine Admin API
- Google Cloud Storage
- Google Cloud Storage JSON API

What did I missed?

Comment: Without the text of the HttpError, it's difficult to say. Do you mind posting it?

Comment: Or the full command that was run and its parameters.